# Do I need to manually free swift instance which is referred in objective-c

Tags: swift, objective-c

I have CBPeripheral extension written in objective-c, and a variable bleManagerStore refers to BleManagerStore instance. When the CBPeripheral instance auto-released, will the reference count to bleManagerStore automatically decreased too? If not, how do I solve it?

I have the same question with the variable currentSeq too.

Thanks.

### objective-c code

```
@implementation CBPeripheral(com_megster_ble_extension)
BleManagerStore *bleManagerStore;
NSNumber *currentSeq;

-(void)setBleManagerStore:(BleManagerStore*) store {
    bleManagerStore = store;
}

-(BleManagerStore*)getBleManagerStore {
    return bleManagerStore;
}
-(void) setSeq:(NSNumber*) seq {
  currentSeq = seq;
}

@end
```

---

### Swift code

```
class BleManager {
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral?
    func test() {
        peripheral?.setBleManagerStore(BleManagerStore())
        peripheral?.setSeq(NSNumber(value: 12))
    }
}
```

---

Comment: As long as you have ARC (automated reference counting) enabled (which, you probably have enabled, unless specifically disabled) - you don't need to manually free the bleManagerStore instance. However, it seems like you're using parent -> child relationship where a child keeps a reference to parent. unless your BleManagerStore is a singleton, this will probably lead to a complex object management lifecycle i.e. what happens if the BleManagerStore is deallocated? In cases like this, look into a delegate model, or keeping a weak reference to the parent (BleManagerStore).

Comment: Also, just try it and check the memory debugger to see what happens to the instance. You'll learn more.

Comment: This ObjC code is also probably wrong. It's creating static (i.e. global) properties, shared by all peripherals, not per-peripheral instance variables. So calling `-setSeq:` modifies *every* peripheral's `currentSeq`. You can't add properties in a category this way. As mani notes, you don't need any manual memory management; ARC will take care of it. But when CBPeripheral is released, it will not release bleManagerStore because that's not an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Swift handles memory automatically using [Automatic Reference Counting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). Which automatically frees up memory from class instances that don't require it anymore.

However, Reference counting **only** works with instances of classes, as mentioned in the swift language guide

> Reference counting applies only to instances of classes. Structures and enumerations are value types, not reference types, and aren’t stored and passed by reference.